# How to join two separate arrays into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I do have two different arrays namely,

["Laddoo", "Sweets", "Mixtures", "1FixBoxes", "Chips"]

[120, 185, 150, 145, 130]

I need to Join them as a single array like this.

```
data:  [
{
  name: 'Laddoo',
  y: 120,
    
}, 
{
  name: 'Sweets',
  y: 185
}, 
{
  name: 'Mixtures',
  y: 150
}, 
{
  name: '1FixBoxes',
  y: 145
},
{
  name: 'Chips',
  y: 130
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()`

```
const names = ["Laddoo", "Sweets", "Mixtures", "1FixBoxes", "Chips"];
const yValues = [120, 185, 150, 145, 130];

const transformedData = names.map((name, index) => ({name: name, y: yValues[index]}));

console.log(transformedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call .map on either array and use the index to get the value of the other array.

```
nameArray.map((val, index) => { name: val, y: yArray[index] });
```